# CSS grid float alignment

Tags: html, css

**This is what I want:**

[image]

**And this is what I have (I want the bottom left box scooted up):**

[image]

Here is my CSS so far.

```
.grid {
  padding:0px;
  margin:10px auto;
  width:100%;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.grid li {
  display: block;
  width:  361px;
  float: left;
  background: #fff;
  margin:6px 19px 6px 0px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow:    0px 2px 1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.4);
  box-shadow:         0px 2px 1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.4);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Please provide some HTML code or JSFiddle jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://inkbud.com/wp-content/plugins/juicyreviews/get_reviews.php

Comment: or look at http://isotope.metafizzy.co/